# Rails 7 Upgrade - ActionCable Connection::connect() is never called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade, actioncable

## Problem

I upgraded a Rails 5 app to Rails 7. My page at https://localhost:3000/squirrel no longer receives messages after successfully negotiating a connection with the server, as seen here:

[image]

Here is the log from Rails:

```
Started GET "/squirrel" for ::1 at 2023-04-26 16:20:31 -0400
Processing by SquirrelController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:61:in `load_or_create_current_user'
  Rendering layout layouts/squirrel.haml
  Rendering squirrel/index.haml within layouts/squirrel
  Rendered squirrel/index.haml within layouts/squirrel (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 38)
  Rendered layout layouts/squirrel.haml (Duration: 192.9ms | Allocations: 161402)
Completed 200 OK in 212ms (Views: 194.3ms | ActiveRecord: 3.6ms | Allocations: 172585)


Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2023-04-26 16:20:35 -0400
Started GET "/cable" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2023-04-26 16:20:35 -0400
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
```

I have a barely edited connection.rb:

```
# app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :secret_id

    def connect
      raise "Why isn't this error being raised?"
      self.secret_id = cookies['secret_id']
    end
  end
end
```

I've added the `raise` line for debugging. To isolate the problem, I've tried making the connection with a simple call within Chrome's console:

[image]

This results in the same output from the Rails log, with the `raise` having no effect.

When I switch back to my (working) Rails 5 branch, doing the above WebSocket() call results in an error as expected.

```
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2023-04-26 16:47:34 -0400
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2023-04-26 16:47:34 -0400
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
There was an exception - RuntimeError(Why isn't this error being raised?)
```

If I comment the `raise`, I get this line instead, which is what I want:

```
Registered connection (156836862)
```

## Config

My `routes.rb` has nothing regarding action cable, which means it's just doing whatever the default is.

This is what it looks like when I start the server:

```
rvm in /Users/toddcesere/projects/sites/cesoid do rails s -b 'ssl://localhost:3000?key=config/ssl/localhost.key&cert=config/ssl/localhost.crt'
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.4 application starting in development 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.12 (ruby 3.1.2-p20), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on ssl://localhost:3000?key=config/ssl/localhost.key&cert=config/ssl/localhost.crt
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

config/cable.yml (I'm working in the development environment)

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  channel_prefix: cesoid_development

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDISCLOUD_URL") { '' } %>
  channel_prefix: cesoid_production
```

## Guessing

Maybe the server changed between Rails 5 and Rails 7 in a way that makes my (fragile) development setup no longer work. Access through port 3000? https with the localhost certificate? It requires some additional gem for web sockets now?